# What happened to my menu Icons?

Tags: icons, appmenu

I have been using Natty for a month now and everything is running smoothly there is only one or two problems I have come across (on my Machine). This problem is as far as I can tell in relation to the global menu, I like to enable menu Icons as I feel having a visual cue makes it quicker to find the menu item quicker however almost all of the Icons are being replaced with not found image icons. Is this a bug or is there a simple fix for this?

[image: global menu with missing Icons]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [a known whishlist bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/dbusmenu/+bug/633334).

Point is: the icons [aren't suppsed to be there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/608584) by default (it's about the `/desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons` GConf key), so it looks like nobody really cared about that case.

Comment: Somehow Allan has the gconf key turned on (it was off on my fresh install). You can turn it off by entering this in a Terminal: `gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/menus_have_icons --type bool true`

Comment: I have added myself to the bug htorque. I don't think I'm the only one who likes the visual cue's in the menu (I'm sure I heard somewhere a picture is worth a thousand words) this is particularly important in an application like Inkscape

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a simple fix, but most of my missing icon problems went away after I applied all available updates.

Also I found that some themes seem to eliminate the problem, so if you still see the problem after applying all your updates, try changing your theme.

Comment: I've changed theme a few times and changed icons but the problem persists I'll throw a few reboots at it and see if there's any change. Ps stop changing your Avatar mid question ;)